# Why do Windows VMware VMs get suspended at night?

Tags: windows-7, vmware

Every morning, I notice my virtual machines running Windows are in a Suspended state, while my Linux ones a re still running. I'm observing this with Windows 7 VMs, 32 and 64 bits).

Is it due to Windows 7 or to VMware, can I configure something so that the VMs don't get suspended ?

In case it matters, I'm using vSphere client on a laptop running Mac OSX with Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection, which I disconnect from the network at night.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just like your primary Windows 7 host. It's set to suspend/hibernate after a length of time. You may want to check the power settings under the advanced options and set it to not suspend.